# L293B unable to deliver power to dc motors on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: power

I have a problem delivering power to 2 dc motors using L293B on Raspberry Pi3B+
I run the following code:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)#To L239 Pin2
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT) #To L239 Pin7
GPIO.setup(07, GPIO.OUT) #L293 Enable Pin1
pwm=GPIO.PWM(07, 800) #Seto GPIO No.7 as PWM at 800Hz

def F():
# Wheels Forward
    pwm.start(100.0) 
    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(100.0)
    GPIO.output(11, True)
    GPIO.output(12, False)
    GPIO.output(07, True) #Enable Pin ON
```

But my motor is running very slow as if I have used around 30% of the available power. When I connect my battery directly on the motor, it runs like hell but running the above script will barely move the wheel.

Note: I use L293B for controlling the motors.
The above code is for 1 motor.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: what happens if you set the output pin to HIGH or LOW (whichever value turns on the motor) .... do not use PWM

Comment: Not sure, haven't check this.
Just an update, I have connected L293 with 5V (pin2) on Vss replacing 3.3V (pin 1) previously provided from RPi and the motors have shown a much better response.
Note: The motors are powered from a 12V AA pack.

Comment: You might be wiring the L293B up wrong. Are you sure that the V+ pins are hooked up correctly? (One to the Pi's 5V, one to the 12V pack).

Comment: As stated before, I was connecting the V+ of the L293 to the 3.3V instead of 5V.